# How to split a cell value into multiple rows while keeping other cell data?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a range of cells like the below:

```
Col A         | Col B      | Col C | Col D
apple, orange | red, green | 5     | 10
pear, banana  | blue       | 20    | 40
```

I want to get a result that looks like:

```
Col A 
apple-red-5-10
apple-green-5-10
orange-red-5-10
orange-green-5-10
pear-blue-20-40
banana-blue-20-40
```

I am concatenating values in each row across multiple columns, but if a cell contains a comma separated list of an item, I need to treat each entry as if they belong in a new row with other column data included.

I first reference the range belonging to the four columns I am interested in concatenating.

```
Dim cellRef1 As Range
Set cellRef1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("I2:I60")
Dim cellRef2 As Range
Set cellRef2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("E2:E60")
Dim cellRef3 As Range
Set cellRef3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("D2:D60")
Dim cellRef4 As Range
Set cellRef4 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("H2:H60")
```

Then for the columns which would have comma separated entries (second and fourth), I create an array to store each value e.g.:

```
Dim Array_Two As Variant
Array_Two = cellRef2.Value
```

So I would have an array along the lines of

```
 ("apple, orange", "pear,banana")
```

I wanted to loop through each array to create a sub-array where I want to split the entries by a comma and store them in a new array.

e.g. I want:

```
Array_Two_A = ("apple", "orange")
Array_Two_B = ("pear", "banana)
```

So I can later access each entry and concatenate them.

I wanted to do this using:

```
Dim Array_Two_New() As String

For x = LBound(Array_Two) To UBound(Array_Two)
    Array_Two_New = Split(Array_Two(x, 1), ",")
Next x
```

Which kind of works, but the problem is I can't figure out how to dynamically create an array that I can later access.

e.g. as is my code will keep overwriting the Array_Two_New array with the first value the string in Array_Two(x,1) is split into.

I thought I could add Array_Two_New(x) in my code so that I get a result like:

```
Array_Two_New(1) = ("apple", "orange")
Array_Two_New(2) = ("pear", "banana")
```

And I could later access the value I want e.g.

```
Array_Two_New(1)(1) = "apple"
Array_Two_New(1)(2) = "orange"
Array_Two_New(2)(1) = "pear" // etc.
```

I think I'm confusing the syntax here.

I think I need to use an object but I am not too familiar with them.

I found these articles but I couldn't follow the explanations.

[VBA: Split cell values into multiple rows and keep other data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42425208/vba-split-cell-values-into-multiple-rows-and-keep-other-data)
[Splitting an array into multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44656750/splitting-an-array-into-multiple-rows)

Comment: You could have a loop through A which splits "apple, orange" and then an inner loop which splits B "red, green" ? `Split` produces an array.

Comment: So I have two different loops to split the cells in the columns that have comma separated entries.

The problem is that each column will have multiple cells I need to split, and I need to split cells from multiple columns.

Comment: So I think I need two arrays - one for storing each cell value in a given column range, and one for storing the results from the cells I split. 

My problem is once I split the cells, I don't know how to best store the elements in this new second array and later access them.

Comment: e.g. If I initially get one array that contains "apple, orange", "banana, pear, grape" as two elements, I want to create a new array "apple", "orange" that has two elements and another array "banana", "pear" that contains three elements. 

But I'll need more than just two new arrays - I'll need to keep creating a new array every time I split a cell and be able to access its elements at a later point. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I've posted an answer below so give it a try and let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works, based on your example.

If you have a lot of data, you might want to consider writing your data into an array and only reading back once you've done the concatentation as this will speed things up considerably.

```
Sub x()

Dim vA As Variant, vB As Variant, i As Long, j As Long, r As Range

For Each r In Range("A1:A10")
    vA = Split(r, ",")
    vB = Split(r.Offset(, 1), ",")
    For i = LBound(vA) To UBound(vA)
        For j = LBound(vB) To UBound(vB)
            Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2) = Trim(vA(i)) & "-" & Trim(vB(j)) & "-" & r.Offset(, 2).Value & "-" & r.Offset(, 3).Value
        Next j
    Next i
Next r

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the delay... was tweaking it to my real program and I got it to work. Thanks so much for your help! :)